# Parallele Computing - 2 vs. 4 processor speed

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

I am evaluating a code which ends with Table having `ParallelEvaluate` of a function `XXXX[phi, theta, si]`. For a grid of 225 points, a normal 2 processor laptop is taking 7 h as compared to 8.30 h by a high end Xeon 4 processor computer. CPU and memory usage for laptop and computer are about 66% vs 99% and 700MB vs 900 MB respectively. Will be thankful for any suggestion on how to improve the evaluation speed on computer. Thanks

Comment: Okay, having skimmed through the code, I can say that your actual problem is not parallelization but your coding style. You use far too much symbolic computation; you use unpacked arrays (in particular because you mix integer, symbolic and machine precision numbers in arrays); you recompute data over and over again (have a look at the many `Sort` and `SortBy` commands); instead of concise function calls with purely numerical input and output, you use replace rules;...

Comment: Running `XXXX[0, 0, 0]` once takes 135 s on my machine. I guess this can be executed 100--1000 times faster with proper refactoring of your code (and probably by using `Compile` here and there).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You are correct, there could be many ways to write code, and as someone writing such complicated Mathematica code for the first time, I might have not opted the most efficient sub-steps. Though my Q about parallelization remains. Let us consider for any code taking x sec to evaluate at one point, how can we scale it linearly with no of points and no of processors (using ParallelTable or ParallelEvaluate or any other method) ? Will be thankful for your suggestion on that. In the meantime, I will try to modify code to reduce time/point "x" by incorporating your suggestion. Thx

Comment: @user49535 I think that your replacement rules are killing you. If I run `DSC[0, 0, 0, 1]` by itself, I get output that's over 12 million bytes because the code is unable to multiply the numbers by your f values since they're one of the last things to be defined. If possible, I would try to store the f values as actual numbers in a matrix. It looks to me like the output of DSC is actually supposed to be a matrix with 36 rows and 3 columns, where the second 2 columns are just indices, so it should be on the order of 1000 bytes.

Comment: DSC could be a cause of slow speed. Though, f are functions of m which is a index running the Do loop in XXXX. For each DSC cycle of m, f[m] are already known though, for next cycle of m+1, f[m+1] needs to come through the XXXX only. Please see at the top, f[0] is defined at the beginning. Hard to think of an alternative method of doing so. For the moment I am ok with whatever time one point is taking to evaluate. Making it scale linearly with no of points and processors would also be a great help. You suggestion of not using exact points (using ".") already working up to some extent. thanks

Comment: By the way how you found out the no of bytes involved in DSC calculations?

Comment: @user49535 I just use `ByteCount[DSC[0, 0, 0, 1]]` to find out how big the output is. If you can figure out how to make it so that each function only outputs a matrix of numbers, I honestly think you'll see at least a 100x speedup and go from 480 minutes to 4.8 minutes. In terms of parallelization, usually `ParallelTable` does the trick. I'm not sure why it doesn't here, but I wonder if MMA is maybe seeing that values from one calculation on one thread will change the result of another thread?

Comment: @user49535 Out of curiosity, is there a particular resource (like an algorithm from a book or code in another language) that you're trying to emulate? I'm trying to figure out what f does, but it's difficult. XX1 calls XXXX which calls DSC -> SEM -> SE -> TrueStrain -> EigenStrain which contains these f variables, but the computer doesn't know what they are yet.  Then we go all the way back up the stack to DSC, and some of the f variables are replaced with *other* f variables but still not assigned a value, until we go back up to XXXX and have `dsc/.R[m-1]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88492/discussion-between-massdefect-and-user49535).

Comment: @user49535 Why did you remove the code from your question? Without it, this is virtually unanswerable and is at risk of being closed.

Comment: Was not getting any response at all. Will be happy to add code again if anyone willing to help. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing the exact function (I assume it's something fairly long, possibly involving integrals or differential equations), I can only make the following suggestions:

It looks like you're using exact numbers. If this is necessary for your application, then there's probably not a lot you can do, but exact numbers usually slow things down substantially. If you can, use `Real` numbers (just place a dot after the numbers like `{phi, 0., Pi/4., Pi/56.}`. If you need more precision than that but don't necessarily require the infinite precision of exact numbers, you can also do this: `` {phi, 0`50, Pi/4`50, Pi/56`50} ``. This will give you 50 digits of precision to work with which should make your final answer pretty close to the exact answer.

The other thing I would try is:

```
XX1 = ParallelTable[
  {XXXX[phi, theta, si]], phi, theta, si},
  {phi, 0, Pi/4, Pi/56},
  {theta, 0, ArcCot[Cos[phi]], ArcCot[Cos[phi]]/14},
  {si, 0 Pi, 0 Pi, 0}
]
```

I think that `ParallelTable` is a better way to handle this than `ParallelEvaluate`. On a trial function, I see about a 100x speedup. `ParallelEvaluate` is simply evaluating your exact same function 4 times at each data point rather than splitting the task into multiple threads.

If you can, combine both things for the best speedup.

I hope this helps a bit! There are some people on here that are amazing at optimizing, perhaps they will be able to improve the speed even more. If it's possible, I would recommend posting your `XXXX` function unless it's insanely long.

Comment: Thanks @LukasLang ! How do you type grave accents without it interpreting them as the inline code markers? I tried backslashes before them, but that didn’t help.

Comment: You have to increase the amount of enclosing accents: ``` `` Code`with`accents`` ```. If you need double accents, you enclose the code with three, and so on (edit: for some reason, it doesn't work in the comment section - but you can edit your answer to see how it's done)

Comment: @LukasLang Oh, I see! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks both of you. three points 1. I do not necessary need to use exact values of (theta, phi) if it can speed up, can use ".". 2. I tried to use ParalleleTable first, but in contrast to your experience, it took 30h/48h for 4/2 processor computer as compared to 8h/7h for ParallelEvaluate. 4 - 8 times slower. 3. How can I combine both...you mean ParallelTable[ParallelEvaluate[. ??

Comment: @user49535 As MassDefect already pointed out, using `ParallelEvaluate` here **does not make sense at all**. It enforces that the same value is computed on each of your CPU cores which is why you won't gain any speedup. It really depends on your actual function `XXXX ` whether `ParallelTable` can help at all. If it is a pure function then `ParallelTable` should help.But if `XXXX` has **side effects** (like modifying data that has to be used by another thread) then it is hard to parallelize the execution. In a nutshell, we cannot give any further suggestions without knowing `XXXX`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Please see the edited Q. I have added the code.

Comment: @user49535 Sorry, I meant to combine both Machine Precision numbers and ParallelTable, not combining ParallelTable and ParallelEvaluate. I will take a look when I have time, but ParallelEvaluate should not produce any speed up and should not be necessary.